# C++ 2 dimention pointer array initialization C2440

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

If this looks familiar, it is.  I asked a question on this last week but this time I am using pointers.
I need to input the amount of candSize to initialize the array.  If I take out the for loop, the function runs to insert a single char and a number for votes, function ends and I can print it so I know  that is working as it should for now.  My problem is where I try to get the 2nd dimension on the candList array.  The '=' sign on the line after the for loop is getting a squiggly faulting for

> '=' : cannot convert from 'char *' to 'char'

My text is showing this and it is the only option I have found here and other places, and they work.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>
#include<array>
using namespace std;

void dataInput ( char* &candList, double* &voteList, int candSize );
//void processing ( char candName[][nameCol], double votes[][voteCol], int& index );
//void print ( char candName[][nameCol], double votes[][voteCol], int index );
int main ( )
{
    int candSize, voteSize;
    cout << "Enter number of Candidates: ";
    cin >> candSize;
    cout << endl;
    voteSize = candSize;
    char **candList = new char*[candSize];
    double **voteList = new double*[voteSize];
    for (int a = 0; a < candSize;a++)
         candList[a] = new char[8];**"Problem line"**
    for (int c = 0;c < candSize;c++)
        voteList[c] = new double[2];**"Problem line"**
    dataInput ( *candList, *voteList, candSize );

    for (int b = 0;b < candSize;b++)
    {
        cout << candList[b] << " ";
        cout << voteList[b];
        cout << endl;
    }
    system ( "Pause" );
}
void dataInput ( char *& candList, double *& voteList, int candSize )
{
    for (int a = 0; a < candSize;a++)
    {
        cout << "Enter candidate name: ";
        cin >> candList[a];
        cout << "Enter votes for candidate: ";
        cin >> voteList[a];
    }

}
```

[Output of current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B97pl.png)

Comment: Where are you trying to get the 2nd dimension of `candList`?

Comment: yes, I need to be able to put a name in candList but I can only get a single character.

Comment: @Gaben My problem is where I try to get the 2nd dimension on the candList array. The '=' sign on the line after the for loop is getting a squiggly faulting for

Comment: Show (by a comment in the code) which line you get the error if you want help! This would be far more effective as we would immediately see the faulty line. Obviously if the first level in a 1 dimension array the second level is a single character.

Comment: You probably meant to allocate an array of `char*` pointers, as in `char** candList = new char*[candSize];`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I tried that and it did not work. When I tried to enter more than one character the program went hayware and when i did did one character I got a lot of garbage printed.

Comment: @Phil1970 I separated out the line giving me the problem.

Comment: The code shown doesn't process any input, so I'm not sure what you mean by "enter more than one character". Clearly, you no longer receive `'=' : cannot convert from 'char *' to 'char'` error message, so the suggestion solved the problem you asked about. Turns out, you have more bugs elsewhere; work on fixing those.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Can you please enlighten me why I don't get the error message anymore?  Becasue I didn't get that message.  Also, can you please enlighten me about the other bugs I have?

Comment: Before, your program failed to compile. Now, you are able to run it, which means you were able to compile it. From this, I conclude that you no longer receive a compiler error. However, you testify that the output of the program doesn't match your expectations. From this, I conclude that the program still contains bugs. You further describe that the problem occurs when you "tried to enter more than one character" - but the code shown doesn't read any character input. From this, I conclude that the problem must needs lie in the code not shown. I am unable to help with the code I cannot see.

Comment: As you market question with C++11, i assume you have access to compatible compiler, instead of using these scary things like array, you can take advantage of c++ containers:https://www.godbolt.org/z/jV2kpj

Comment: You should use `std::string` and `std::vector` as it simplify things a lot.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik edited in the function for data input

Comment: You changed `candList` to be `char**` - but you are not passing `char**` to `dataInput`. You are effectively passing `candList[0]`, a one-dimensional array of chars. `cin >> candList[a]` reads one character, since `candList[a]` is of type `char`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you for your help.  I would not have found that I needed the extra *

Answer (score 0):

I found all my errors and found the fix.  @Igor Tandetnik.
I needed the extra * in certain spots that I would not have found.
Here is the code that has fixed the problems that I had.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>
#include<array>
using namespace std;

void dataInput ( char** &candList, double** &voteList, int candSize );
//void processing ( char candName[][nameCol], double votes[][voteCol], int& index );
//void print ( char candName[][nameCol], double votes[][voteCol], int index );
int main ( )
{
    int candSize, voteSize;
    cout << "Enter number of Candidates: ";
    cin >> candSize;
    cout << endl;
    voteSize = candSize;
    char **candList = new char*[candSize];
    double**voteList = new double*[voteSize];

    for (int a = 0; a < candSize;a++)
         candList[a] = new char[8];
    for (int c = 0;c < candSize;c++)
        voteList[c] = new double[2];
    dataInput ( candList, voteList, candSize );

    for (int b = 0;b < candSize;b++)        
    {
        cout << candList[b] << " ";
        cout << *voteList[b];
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

}
void dataInput ( char **&candList, double **&voteList, int candSize )
{
    for (int a = 0; a < candSize;a++)   
        //for (int b = 0;b < 8;b++)
    {
        cout << "Enter candidate name: ";
        cin >> candList[a];
        cout << "Enter votes for candidate: ";
        cin >> voteList[a][0];
    }   
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nm1d7.png)

Now I just need to do all the calculations needed.  Hopefully since I don't need to make any more pointers I should be ok.